# Swipe in Landscape view using uigestureswipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Can we implement `UISwipeGesture` in the landscape view of images?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

In your view did load (to add gesture recognizer to your view):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[mainSlideShowImageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[mainSlideShowImageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];
```

Then implement the following method:

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
   {
      //Do moving
   }

- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer 
{
  // do moving
}
```

Comment: I used this code but it only helps to swipe the images in portrait mode But still landscape mode cannot be swiped Thanks rptwsthi

Comment: dude I'm, using it in landscape mode :D

Comment: But when i used the rotate left option in the hardware option of the simulator it doesn't work. ie no swipe gesture is recognized in any direction  Thanks mate

Comment: I implemented it in the iphone also still no responsemate

Comment: one doubt for the landscape mode should i put the code I used it in the viewdidload. Is it right?

Comment: You are right bro it recognize gesture in only, direction, whether it is landscape or portrait, and i don't have any clue yet to sort it out, for the both direction.